# Minimum value of biggest term of increasing sequence

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

I have a problem as follows. Given $t_1\leq \cdots \leq t_k$ a non-decreasing sequence of integers, let $s_1<\cdots< s_k$ be another sequence of integers so that $t_i\leq s_i$ for every $i=1,\ldots ,k$. What is the minimum value of $s_k$?

There is an algorithm to find the minimum value of $s_k$ for each input $(t_1, \ldots ,t_k)$, however I prefer to have a closed formula for that value.

Can someone help me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like
$$\max\{\,t_i+k-i\mid 1\le i\le k\,\} $$
to me.

Comment: Can you give me more details please?

Comment: @mapping It's very easy to prove from the formula. Let $m$ be the value stated in the answer.  Prove that $s_k \ge t_i + k - i$ for each $i$, thus showing that $s_k \ge m$ necessarily.  Then show that setting $s_i = m - k + i$ satisfies the conditions.

Comment: Well it's very clear to me now. Thank you very much!